# Android: issues centering text view horizontally + button text vertically

Tags: android

I need to center that two information ("123456789" and "RACCOLTA PUNTI") in the screen.
This is the (not) desidered result:

[image]

And this is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_left">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
            android:id="@+id/card_number"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:id="@+id/name_campaign"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/view_anchor"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_add"
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_deduct"
            android:id="@+id/button_deduct"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another one issues: you can note that text in button are not centered (vertically). How I can center (vertically) them? Thank you very much

Comment: use center instead of a center_horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove android:gravity attribute in all the views.

Set the **android:layout_gravity** of text views to **center_horizontal**.

There is a difference between gravity and layout_gravity.

android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the view it is used on and android:layout gravity sets the gravity of the view/layout in its parent.

By default android:gravity is set to center and android:layout_gravity is set to left.

I have made changes in the code w.r.t to your issues.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_left">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:id="@+id/card_number"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:id="@+id/name_campaign"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/view_anchor"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_add"
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_deduct"
        android:id="@+id/button_deduct"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your textView from:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

And add

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the text in your TextView set `android:layout_width` to `match_parent`

To center the text inside your Botton set `android:gravity` to `center` like mentioned by @Blackbelt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_left">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
            android:id="@+id/card_number"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:id="@+id/name_campaign"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/view_anchor"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_add"
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_deduct"
            android:id="@+id/button_deduct"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use layout_gravity tag instead of the gravity tag on the textview

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to both textviews

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

And this line to both buttons

```
android:gravity="center"
```